# npm scripts in sequence with expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, npm, nightwatch.js

I have three scripts I need to run in a sequence, the middle being starting an expressjs server.

Here is my scripts:

1. `npm run build`
2. `npm start`
3. `node ./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/runner.js -c ./nightwatch.json`

The reason being is nightwatch requires a server to be running to test against, but when starting expressjs I am stuck in the log/process without it continuing to the next script. When I have `npm start &` it does run it in the background but takes longer to start than nightwatch third script so nightwatch makes calls to the haven't-start-yet server and fails.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to use [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) package to run your server as a deamon and use sleep command to wait your server to be up before launching nightwatchjs.

Below is the npm script command :

```
forever start app.js && sleep 5 && nightwatch --env chrome,default && forever stopall
```

Don't forget to stop all deamon at the end

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You could add a script to package.json , for example I added watch script that run 3 commands in sequence , and every command will run only if previous command was successful, so I can just run : npm run watch

```
package.json
"scripts": {
    "nightwatch": "node ./node_modules/nightwatch/bin/runner.js -c
     ./nightwatch.json",
     'build':'.....',
     'start':'.....',
     "watch":'npm run build && npm start && npm run nightwatch'
  }
```

Hope this could help ,is not tested , you could read this [reference](http://www.jayway.com/2014/03/28/running-scripts-with-npm/)

Comment: That's what I currently have, the problem is that the start script is expressjs which is a process that is not closed until you do CMD+C, hence it never goes to the third process.

Comment: try changing && to & ,

Comment: but it takes about 3-4s for server to start while nightwatch starts immediately with no server running and fails